# Aurora-PostgreSQL 12 config param related to CTE

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I wanted to know if there are any Postgres config parameter settings available for CTEs in specific? The reason I am asking this is because we migrated a DB from AWS RDS Postgres to Aurora Postgres with the same major version (Postgres v12). Both the DB's have the same structure/indices/etc., however when we run the same CTE on Aurora, it runs very slow and shows very high IOPS v/s when we run it on RDS, it runs fast and no IOPS issue there. I am assuming that there might be some config setting which is different in RDS v/s Aurora which is causing the issue.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) for the queries?  That should be the first step.

Comment: Yes.. The explain plan on the Aurora looks similar to the RDS and the cost on Aurora is lesser than RDS, however when I check the Aurora logs, I see a lot of temp files being created. The memory params like shared_buffers, work_mem and main_work_mem on Aurora are much higher than RDS. Any suggestions

Comment: Also forgot to mention, updated Aurora instance from 2xL -> 4xL, still high IOPS :-(